# How to to add static title and scrollable content in xaml win8

Tags: c#, xaml, scrollview, mobile-development

I'm trying to add a static headlines or a title in a xaml page , where the user can scroll some content but not the title

```
<Page
x:Class="Advanced8weeks.day1"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:local="using:Advanced8weeks"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
mc:Ignorable="d">

 <!--- I want this block to remain static on the top of the page --> 

<Grid Background="{StaticResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
    <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="80,100,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Day 1 " VerticalAlignment="Top" FontWeight="Bold" FontSize="24" RenderTransformOrigin="0.483,1.826"/>
    <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="80,192,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Legs + cardio (1 min rest between sets) " VerticalAlignment="Top" FontWeight="Bold" FontSize="18"/>

      <!--- From here I want to add a lot of Images and  Button where user can scroll down --> 

        <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="80,287,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="leg extentions 5 x 15 reps " VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="47" FontSize="16"/>
    <Image HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="100" Margin="80,334,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="100" Source="pictures/imag1.png"/>
    <TextBox HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="80,439,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="27" Height="17"/>
    <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="80,417,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Set 1 " VerticalAlignment="Top" RenderTransformOrigin="-0.022,0.231" Width="47" FontSize="14"/>
    <Button Content="OK" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="158,439,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" FontSize="14" Click="Button_Click" Height="37"/>

    <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="752,192,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="" VerticalAlignment="Top"  x:Name="timer" Height="22" Width="59" />
    <ScrollBar HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="472,317,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
    <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="80,506,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Squats 5 x 15 reps " VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="21" Width="148" FontSize="16"/>
    <Image HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="100" Margin="111,555,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="100"/>
    <Image HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="68" Margin="80,541,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="65" Source="pictures/imag2.png"/>
    <TextBox HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="80,623,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="" VerticalAlignment="Top" RenderTransformOrigin="0.203,0.344" Width="64" Height="23"/>
    <Button Content="OK" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="158,617,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" RenderTransformOrigin="0.225,-0.342" Width="54"/>


</Grid>
```

So My first attempt is to add a ScrollViewer , So I did this

```
<Grid Background="{StaticResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
    <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="80,100,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Day 1 " VerticalAlignment="Top" FontWeight="Bold" FontSize="24" RenderTransformOrigin="0.483,1.826"/>
    <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="80,192,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Legs + cardio (1 min rest between sets) " VerticalAlignment="Top" FontWeight="Bold" FontSize="18"/>

      <!--- From here I want to add a lot of Images and   Button where user can scroll down -->

    <ScrollViewer >   

    <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="80,287,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="leg extentions 5 x 15 reps " VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="47" FontSize="16"/>
    <Image HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="100" Margin="80,334,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="100" Source="pictures/imag1.png"/>
    <TextBox HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="80,439,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="27" Height="17"/>
    <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="80,417,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Set 1 " VerticalAlignment="Top" RenderTransformOrigin="-0.022,0.231" Width="47" FontSize="14"/>
    <Button Content="OK" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="158,439,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" FontSize="14" Click="Button_Click" Height="37"/>

    <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="752,192,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="" VerticalAlignment="Top"  x:Name="timer" Height="22" Width="59" />
    <ScrollBar HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="472,317,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
    <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="80,506,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Squats 5 x 15 reps " VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="21" Width="148" FontSize="16"/>
    <Image HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="100" Margin="111,555,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="100"/>
    <Image HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="68" Margin="80,541,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="65" Source="pictures/imag2.png"/>
    <TextBox HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="80,623,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="" VerticalAlignment="Top" RenderTransformOrigin="0.203,0.344" Width="64" Height="23"/>
    <Button Content="OK" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="158,617,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" RenderTransformOrigin="0.225,-0.342" Width="54"/>

    </ScrollViewer>

</Grid>
```

But the VS express is giving me this error :

> The Content property is set multiple times

I would appreciate if someone can explain me what I'm doing wrong and why

Much appreciated ,

Bass

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't add multiple items to `ScrollViewer`, because it's a `ContentControl` and can store only one element. You should put any `Panel` inside your `ScrollViewer` (`Grid`, `StackPanel`, `DockPanel` and so on) which will contain all your elements:

```
<ScrollViewer>   
    <Grid>
    ...
    </Grid>
</ScrollViewer>
```

Comment: Thank you , I understand better now